# Use Date Library in Extendscript (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, date, libraries, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I'm new to Indesign Scripting, but I'm working on an InDesign CC Script, where I would need to work a lot with date-functions.

I wanted to know if it's possible to import a JS Library like date.js or moment.js in Extendscript for that matter?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the library. If the lib is using browser specific functions then not. I had a quick test with date.js and it seems to work. (Like this)

```
#include "date.js"
var d = Date.today().is().friday();
$.writeln (d);
```

Comment: Browser specific ... or anything else that was added to EcmaScript after around 1995 :) I sure could use stuff such as byte arrays!

Comment: Awesome, thank you! One more question: where did you put the date.js file? In the same directory as the script?

Comment: der-lukas yes.  I'ts a relativ path for the include. @Jongware really? 1995 awful. ;(

Comment: @fabiantheblind Done! Thanks again! I'll post some experiences I made later for future reference later! :)

Comment: @fabiantheblind I got one more little question: I can only run my script from Extendscript Toolkit. When I run it from the Scriptpanel, Extendscript Toolkit opens the date.js-File and gives me an Error Message.
Could this be an issue, because ExtendScript doesn't understand all functions of date.js?

Comment: it is possible that some functions are missing. depends on what error you get. I'm collecting prototypes I found useful here https://github.com/fabiantheblind/extendscript.prototypes you can compile it buy running `npm install && grunt build`